# How can I dynamically check if packaged values have changed from a Trigger

Tags: apex

There is a requirement to check if the packaged(managed) field values have been updated by the client. There are around 40+ fields.
 The simplest is to do something like the following:

```
if(Trigger.oldMap.get(obj.Id).fld1__c!=obj.fld1__c))
```

Is there a dynamic way of checking this so that I don't have to check each and every field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of fields you want to use (this could be a field set), and loop over the list of fields per record, using the get method:

```
for (Integer I = 0; I < trigger.new.size(); I++) {
  for (String field: fields) {
    if (Trigger.old[I].get(field) != Trigger.new[I].get(field)) {
      // Whatever
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To add to sfdcfox's answer, this can be achieved by having all the fields in a List<String> chkFlds={'Name', 'TaxFileNumber__c', 'Resident__c'}; as well. This is what I have used since creating Fieldset may not always be viable.  Thanks again sfdcfox

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the fields at once using sObject clone:

```
for (sObject record: Trigger.new) {
  if(Trigger.old.get(record.id).clone(false, false, false, false) != record.clone(false, false, false, false)) {
   // Whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: wow! I didn't think of this approach, but we would like to check only for the fields that are packaged and not worry about the custom fields created by the subscriber. Out of curiosity, will not Trigger.old.get(record.id) != record work?

Comment: @ShaliniSF nope, because of the audit fields. Clone clears out those fields so you get a good comparison.